# Can you create a cookie with leading dot when there is no subdomain

Tags: http, cookies

If I am on a domain without subdomain:

http://domain.com

can I set a cookie with the leading-dot?

.domain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge yes you do. but I didn't get the reason why you need a cookie with leading . when you don't have sub-domains.

preceding period will apply for the current domain and its sub domains.